# How to pull VPN Certificate to put in Cert Store?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, certificates, openconnect

I frequently use the [OpenConnect](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenConnect) plugin for NetworkManager to access VPN resources. However, each time I activate the VPN profile it asks me if I would like to accept the certificate. Is there a way to pull the remote VPN certificate so I can persistently put it in my trusted certificate store?

I am using [nm-applet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Installation) to do all of this from a nice tray icon, but the command-line equivalent also requests that I accept the certificate.

**tldr;** How can you requests certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As openconnect/anyconnect are ssl based, you might try openssl:

```
: | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p'
```

the first certificate returned would be the servers, the last certificate  would be the ca certificate. you could then copy them to /etc/ssl/certs/ (or similar on arch).

(credits for the command go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server#comment19766982_7886248 )

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It's more elegant to replace `echo ""` with `:`.